# Windows 10 виртуальные рабочие столы

Tags: windows-10

Начал активно использовать виртуальные рабочие столы, использую для отдельных программ, которые открыты на весь экран.
Все бы не плохо, но жать постоянно <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> не самое хорошее решение.

Понимаю и знаю что есть горячие клавиши <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>left/right</kbd>. Но тут есть одно **НО**, работает переключение только в одну, обратную сторону. Т.е. с 3го на 2й, с 2го на 1й. Не понимаю почему не работает в другую?

Comment: Попробовал, у меня работает. Что я делаю не так? :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, Мне тоже интересно, что я делаю не так? =)

Comment: Варианты навскидку: не работает кнопка стрелка :) , данное сочетание отлавливается другой программой

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, тоже так подумал, но запущено всего 4 программы, и то, те которые не ловят нажатия глобально, а стрелка работает.

Comment: Хм, странно но на нампаде вправо работает